# Cin and point to function chosen

Tags: c++, function

I am not understanding how to make it so when i input my selection in testSelection for it to point to the function test. How do i go about doing this? Shouldn't it just go there?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int test (int testSelection);

 int main()
 {
int testSelection;

cout << "Welcome to the pizza place!" << endl;
cout << "Choose 1 for pizza or 2 for drinks: ";

cin >> testSelection;


return 0;

}

int test (int testSelection)
{
if (testSelection== 1)
{
    cout << "select your Pizza" << endl;

}
if (testSelection== 2)
{
    cout << "Please select your drink" << endl;

}
else
    cout << "test";

 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the function...

```
cin >> testSelection;
test(testSelection);
```

Basically, you've written a function definition int test(int testSelection) {...code...} but, it's just dormant code until you invoke it by calling it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are asking exactly.  `testSelection` is an int, not a function which returns an int (which `test` is).  Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish here if I'm off track, you never even call `test`.  As far as I can tell, what you actually want is:

```
int test (int testSelection);

int main()
{
   int testSelection;

   cout << "Welcome to the pizza place!" << endl;
   cout << "Choose 1 for pizza or 2 for drinks: ";

   cin >> testSelection;

   // you actually have to call the function...
   test(testSelection);

   return 0;  
}
```

I didn't add any input validation (you should check that the `cin` actually grabbed a valid integer).